# Transferring Pfaff design of a computer

Tags: file-transfer

How do I transfer the contents of a Pfaff Creative Card from my Pfaff 2140 sewing machine to my computer please?  There are two card slots in the sewing machine that take the cards and a transfer cord from the sewing machine to the computer.  I need to transfer the contents of the Creative Card from my sewing machine to my computer which is running Windows 10.

Answer (score 1):

There's an app for that!

http://www.pfaffsoftware.com/support/index.htm?page=updates.htm#vipconfigure

And, a Frequently Asked Questions list at http://vsmsoftware.net/FAQ/VIP/Pfaff/PF_VIP_FAQ.pdf may be helpful since it tells us you need a cable to connect the two.